# displaying the highest votes

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to display the highest votes of the president, vice president and secretary but this query the smallest votes will also be displayed, what will I do?

```
select c.picturename, c.candidate_id, v.position, count(v.candidate_id) as count 
from votes as v 
left outer join candidates as c on c.candidate_id = v.candidate_id 
group by v.candidate_id 
order by count;
```

Comment: ORDER BY MAX() LIMIT 0,1

Comment: how do you determine `vote for president, vice president..` etc?

Comment: I have a vote table. By counting all the same id's but I don't know how to get the highest.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  position
        ,       candidate_id
        ,       count(*)
        from    votes
        where   position = 'president'
        group by
                position
        ,       candidate_id
        order by
                count(*) desc
        limit   1
        )
union all
select  *
from    (
        select  position
        ,       candidate_id
        ,       count(*)
        from    votes
        where   position = 'vice president'
        group by
                position
        ,       candidate_id
        order by
                count(*) desc
        limit   1
        )
union all
select  *
from    (
        select  position
        ,       candidate_id
        ,       count(*)
        from    votes
        where   position = 'secretary'
        group by
                position
        ,       candidate_id
        order by
                count(*) desc
        limit   1
        )
```